# Operation on a sliding window over streaming in Scala using reduceByKeyAndWindow()

Tags: scala, twitter, twitter4j, spark-streaming

I am writing a Spark streaming application, using Scala, where my goal is by reading the Twitter feed every second to calculate the most retweeted statuses in a window of 60 seconds.

What i conceptually want is to get the number of retweets of a status at the end of the sliding window and subtract it from the equivalent number at its start, in order to find the no. of retweets inside the window. The relevant line of code is:

```
val counts = tweets.filter(_.isRetweet).map { status => 
               (status.getText(), status.getRetweetedStatus().getRetweetCount()) 
             }.reduceByKeyAndWindow(*function*, Seconds(60), Seconds(1))
```

So, my question is what function should I use here to achieve the desired result, that is to get the maximum value that `getRetweetCount()` returns inside the window and subtract the minimum value from it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong or making misassumptions here, but you are essentially checking the number of retweets for a status within your window of `Seconds(60)`. To do this, you already have your filter which removes all non-retweeted tweets (`filter(_.isRetweet)`). Now, all you need to do is an aggregation of the retweeted statuses to determine their frequencies.

This can be achieved with the following:

```
val counts = tweets.filter(_.isRetweet).map { status => 
               (status.getText(), null) 
             }.countByValueAndWindow(Seconds(60), Seconds(1))
```

Perhaps after this, you can order by value and gather the most retweeted tweets within that window.

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but then I realized that the public Twitter stream that I am reading just gives me a very small percentage of the global traffic so I am missing many tweets. That is why I am using getRetweetCount(), to see if there are missed retweets in between. So what I would like instead, is to get the max value of the retweet count inside the window and subtract the min value from it, to be sure that I captured everything.